# Retrieving Full Hash Values from Log Messages

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I am currently working on monitoring rejected transactions from a Geth node and facing a challenge with retrieving the full hash of the rejected transactions from the logs.

While utilizing Geth with `--verbosity 5`, the log entries for rejected transactions are truncated, showing only a partial hash like `hash=e8cb6a..fc4198`. I've attempted to modify the regular expression in my script, but the logs themselves appear to be truncated.

Here is an example log entry that I am working with:

```
TRACE[08-01|10:07:12.751] Possible uncle rejected hash=e8cb6a..fc4198 reason="ignore uncle for beacon block"
```

Is there a specific configuration or method to retrieve the full hash value of these rejected transactions from the logs? Your guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Problem slowed after upgrade geth version  >= 1.11.6

Comment: If the problem was solved please describe it in an answer to your question and select it as the solution.
That can be helpful to others in the future.